# Is it possible to print a specific element in dictionary by using element index in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
total = dict(2000_total = 2000_total,
             2007_total = 2007_total,
             2013_total = 2013_total,
             2020_total = 2020_total)
```

Every element in dictionary are 3 by 4 matrixs, is there any way to select a specific matrix in the dictionary by indexing?

my expected output:

```
>total[0] 
>2000_total
```

Comment: The indexes for that dictionary are "2000_total" and etc. Is there some way that index should be associated with `0`? Dictionaries will enumerate in the order entries are added, so maybe `list(total.values())[0]` but you aren't really getting `2000_total`, rather the first thing entered and hopefully they are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can obtain all dictionary keys as a list, then use access the key of interest:

```py
mat = total[total.keys()[0]]
```

The above logic would return the first dictionary element according to insertion order.